# How to print output for different test cases in different lines?

Tags: python

```
t = int(input())
for _ in range(t):
    a, b = 0, 1
    n = int(input())
    count = 0
    if n == 1:
        print(b)
    while count < n:
        print(b, end = " ")
        a, b = b, a+b
        count += 1
```

When I run this code,the answer of of all the inputs gets printed in the same line.

Input:

```
2
7
5
```

my output is:

```
1 1 2 3 5 8 13 1 1 2 3 5
```

The expected output is:

```
1 1 2 3 5 8 13
1 1 2 3 5
```

I want the output in the exact format as I am failing multiple test cases.
This program prints first n numbers of fibonacci series.

Comment: You're printing with `end=" "` so that applies to the last one also. Just add an empty `print()` after the while loop...

Comment: That fixed my problem!Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an `print()` after the while loop as suggested by @Tomerikoo.

Comment: Give credit to @Tomerikoo who gave this solution it first.